# The property 'APPLICATIONID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem and I wasn't able to solve them by looking other solutions. The problem is that I get an application from user. An application can be in different state, I hold the application itself in APPLICATION table and I hold the state of application in APPLICATIONSTATE table. When a user submits an application, a default application state value shall be written to the application state table. During time, the application's state will be changed and each alteration shall be written in APPLICATIONSTATE table.

I am using Entity Framework database first approach, (Oracle EF) and here is my database E-R diagram:

[image: database er diagram]

Here are the partial classes that generated by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class APPLICATION
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public APPLICATION()
    {
        this.APPLICATIONSTATE = new HashSet<APPLICATIONSTATE>();
    }

    public int APPLICATIONID { get; set; }      

    public System.DateTime APPLICATIONDATE { get; set; }

    public short PROVINCEID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> ILCEID { get; set; }
    public decimal AREA { get; set; }
    public bool ISBASEMENTOK { get; set; }
    public string APPLICATIONEXPLAINATION { get; set; }

    public virtual PERSONEL LOJ_PERSONEL { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<APPLICATIONSTATE> LOJ_APPLICATIONSTATE{ get; set; }

}

public partial class APPLICATIONSTATE
{
    public long APPLICATIONSTATEID { get; set; }
    public int APPLICATIONENUM { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CURRENTTIME { get; set; }

    public virtual APPLICATION LOJ_APPLICATION { get; set; }
    public virtual USER LOJ_USER { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Repository pattern, and here is the code section that I try to add new application and application state:

```
    int applicationId = int.minvalue;

    USER myuser = null;

    APPLICATION myApplication = this.gettingFromSomewhere();

    using (HousingEntities model = new HousingEntities())
    {
        applicantuser = model.LOJ_PERSONEL.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PERSONELID == YeniBasvuru.PersonelId);
        myApplication.LOJ_USER = applicantuser;
        model.APPLICATION.Add(myApplication);
        //saving the application
        model.SaveChanges();

        //getting the primary key of newly created application object from database.
        applicationId = this.getMostCurrentIdOfApplication();
        myApplication.APPLICATIONID = applicationId;

        //getting the user that submits application
        applicant = model.USER.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LOJ_USER.USERID == myApplication.LOJ_PERSONEL.USERID);

        //if clause-1
        if(applicant != null)
        {
            //saving the state of the application.
            appState = new APPLICATIONSTATE();

            //3 is the default state for application. When we need to change it to 4, newly row will be added. 
            appState.APPLICATIONSTATEID = 3;
            appState.LOJ_APPLICATION = myApplication;
            appState.LOJ_USER = applicant;

            //I am getting an error here. 
            model.APPLICATIONSTATE.Add(appState);
            model.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    result.TransactionResult = true;
    result.rowId = applicationId;

}
//other catches removed for clarity.    
catch (Exception ex)
{
    islemSonuc = new FunctionResult ( ex, this._olasihataciddiyeti);
    this.writeError(ex);
}
```

I am getting an error in the line that pointed above *The property 'APPLICATIONID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.* error.How can I overcome that error ? Thanks in advance.

How can I overcome that error ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is `myApplication.APPLICATIONID = applicationId;` line. Either `myApplication.APPLICATIONID` should be autogenerated by the database and you don't need that call, or you should do this **before** `model.APPLICATION.Add(myApplication);`

Comment: Ivan, this is not the point. applicationId is being gotten from database, and when I remove the if clause, the code runs without error.

Comment: Which if clause? The one with the SaveChanges inside?

Comment: Where is the `myID` from the question title?

Comment: It was APPLICATIONID. I choose that name for generalization.

Comment: if clause that I mean is the line that contains "if clause-1".

Comment: Well, when you remove the `if` clause, you remove also `model.SaveChanges();` which IMO is generating the exception because you have changed the `APPLICATIONID` of the already tracked `myApplication` object.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Ivan Stoev's solution is right. At the code above,

> appState.LOJ_APPLICATION = myApplication;

is the error point. We make assignment only by setting the primary key of the entity, we do not go to the database. So The EF can not make matches only with primary key information, it also needs additinal information in the background. So , if we change the code as below :

> myApplication = model.APPLICATION(p=>p.APPLICATIONID == applicationId )

Now, myApplication  contains the most fresh information from the database. When we assign it, then EF is able to match entity.